# Return 1 item from each list at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
columns = ['item', 'desc', 'price', 'currency', 'country', 'state', 'postcode']
```

Basically, I want it to print:

```
a item
b desc
c price
etc...
```

I tried doing:

```
for i in range(0, len(columns)):
    for char in chars:
        print(char, columns[i])
```

But that prints each letter with column[i]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` for this:

```py
for char, col in zip(chars, columns):
    print(char, col)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use zip(), iterate then print.

```
zipped = zip(chars, columns)

for item in zipped:
    print(item[0], item[1])
```

Comment: To be honest the other answer here is slightly more concise and doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: @jbflow Then maybe do `print(*item)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a way without an explicit alphabet (which is always error-prone and I've seen many people forget letters):

```
for i, col in enumerate(columns, start=ord('a')):
    print(chr(i), col)
```